# How is it possible to measure expansion of universe

Tags: cosmology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does space expansion not expand matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/why-does-space-expansion-not-expand-matter)

If according to Hubble's law space the expanding then shouldn't everything else along with the space expand and we should not be able to measure this expansion as our tools/measuring sticks would also expand in same proportion

Comment: Hi Nitin, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This question has already been asked on the site, so have a look at that link and see if it tells you what you wanted to know. If not, you're welcome to post another question asking for more detail, but make sure you mention why the existing questions on this topic don't give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, But are we saying that "expansion of space" is different in

Comment: have a look at the first of the links given  in the duplicate answer http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/gr-qc/pdf/0508/0508052v1.pdf. It helps to understand the mathematics of the case by a simple example, of how the effect of expansion on bound systems depends on the strength of the interaction that keeps the system bound and the rate of expansion. Simple logic should tell us something like that, otherwise we would never know that anything is expanding.

Comment: continued: we can see the galaxies expanding because the gravitational interaction is very weak. An atom and even worse, a nucleus, are bound by electromagnetic and strong forces which are   orders of magnitude stronger than gravitational forces.